# Cannot find any make sense infomation from error when run react-native run-android command

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native project, I develop on Mac is ok, everything run well. But when I run on windows machine, I get the error:

Environment:
OS: windows
target: Android
version: "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "^0.72.7",

```
C:/02-DATA-USER/TestCode/Application/CoffeeShop/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/common/cpp/react/renderer/components/safeareacontext/RNCSafeAreaViewShadowNode.cpp:85:9: error: no type named 'Style' in namespace 'facebook::yoga'
yoga::Style adjustedStyle = getConcreteProps().yogaStyle;
~~~~~~^
```

1 warning and 6 errors generated.

I canot find any make sense infomation

```
 C:/02-DATA-USER/TestCode/Application/CoffeeShop/node_modules/react-native-svg/android/src/main/jni/../../../../common/cpp\react/renderer/components/rnsvg/RNSVGImageShadowNode.h:47:28: note: passing argument to parameter 'props' here
        Props::Shared const &props,
                             ^
  3 errors generated.
```

the error look strange

```
  void adopt(ShadowNode& shadowNode) const override {
                                             ^
  C:/Users/pxvuong/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f5b6369cea5fc99dae80dd8391bca788/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.72.7-debug/prefab/modules/react_nativemodule_core/include\react/renderer/core/ConcreteComponentDescriptor.h:209:16: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'facebook::react::ConcreteComponentDescriptor<facebook::react::RNCSafeAreaViewShadowNode>::adopt' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter ('const ShadowNode::Unshared &' (aka 'const shared_ptr<facebook::react::ShadowNode> &') vs 'facebook::react::ShadowNode &')
    virtual void adopt(ShadowNode::Unshared const &shadowNode) const {
                 ^
```

Alot of error look are same.

```
 7 errors generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Users\\pxvuong\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        -C ^
        "C:\\02-DATA-USER\\TestCode\\Application\\CoffeeShop\\android\\app\\.cxx\\Debug\\5c381024\\arm64-v8a" ^
        appmodules ^
        react_codegen_RNCViewPager ^
        react_codegen_RNVectorIconsSpec ^
        react_codegen_reactnativemmkv ^
        react_codegen_rngesturehandler_codegen ^
        react_codegen_rnscreens ^
        react_codegen_rnsvg ^
        react_codegen_safeareacontext
    from C:\02-DATA-USER\TestCode\Application\CoffeeShop\android\app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Looks like errors in Windows C++. You can debug /gradlew installDebug --stacktrace, or --info, or get in touch with the github source for further information.

Setting GRADLE_USER_HOME in environment variables
Verify that you have the necessary rights to access files and run the command.
Verify that your Gradle files are properly synchronised and that the Android SDK and Gradle are located in the correct locations inside the offline project structure.
 Look for updates on Gradle.